# How to Determine Whether ALL of the words of a Substring are included, in any order, in a Mainstring?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How do I use an Excel Macro to determine true/false whether ALL of the words of a substring are included, in any order, in a mainstring? For example, I want to check whether the words in this substring "ford F150" are included in the mainstring "like new f150 ford black", which should return true.

I tried the code examples above, but they didn't work.

I'm guessing the way to do this is to split the substring into an array and then check whether each element of the array is in the mainstring. If ALL of the elements of the substring are in the mainstring then true.

I'm using VBA 7.1. Right now my macro runs, but it always returns TRUE no matter what text I search. Maybe it's an issue with InStr comparing method? Maybe it's an issue storing strings elements inside an array? Here's my macro:

```
Sub Macro 1()

Dim MainString As String
Dim SubString As String
Dim SubStringArray() As String
Dim bFound As Boolean

MainString = Cells(1, 1).Text
SubString = Cells(2, 1).Text
SubStringArray() = Split(SubString, " ")
bFound = False

For Each element In SubStringArray
    If InStr(MainString, element) <> 0 Then
    bFound = True
    Exit For
    End If
Next

Cells(1, 7) = bFound

End Sub
```

I also want to make sure I do not get partial matches such as "ford" should not be found in "fording". I only want to check on complete words.

Comment: This why you use `Option Explicit` - so that undeclared variables like `elemement` won't trip you up and waste your time...

Comment: You have a check, InStr(MainString, elemement) >= 0. If instr returns 0 it means string not found. So bfound will be true always.Is that the issue? Change condition to InStr(MainString, elemement) >0 and try.

Comment: @Tim I caught that misspelling and fixed it. Thanks for the tip on "Option Explicit".

Comment: @Valli I tried changing it to "> 0", but still get the same result. Note, I believe InStr returns error if the Substring is not found in the Mainstring...that's why I thought ">= 0" or even "<> 0" would all work the same.

Comment: If you want to take word boundaries into account then you will need to do a little more work, maybe even using regular expressions...

Comment: Instr will return 0 when substring not found in the main string. Instr to will return 1 when the search string is empty. In your case, when element is empty the if loop is successful. Add one more condition to check if element is empty or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are saying a non-partial match is anything where there is a space on both sides of the searched text (i.e. you don't want to say that `"ford"` should match with `" ford."`) then the following should work:

```
'Macro names cannot contain spaces
'Sub Macro 1()
Sub Macro1()

    Dim MainString As String
    Dim SubString As String
    Dim SubStringArray() As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    MainString = UCase(Cells(1, 1).Text) ' use a consistent case so that "F150"
    SubString = UCase(Cells(2, 1).Text)  ' will match "f150"
    SubStringArray() = Split(SubString, " ")
    bFound = True ' Start by assuming that everything will match

    For Each element In SubStringArray
        If InStr(" " & MainString & " ", " " & element & " ") = 0 Then
            'Exit if we have found something that doesn't match
            bFound = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Cells(1, 7) = bFound

End Sub
```

Comment: QUESTION: How would I modify this if I wanted to check whether the Substring exists in the Mainstring with the Substring words in any order AND with the words next to one another? For example, "F150 Green" or "Green F150" could both be found in "New Green F150 Sale", but both would NOT be found in "Green New F150".

Comment: @msch382 You would change it with a lot of difficulty!  Generically, I can't think of any easy way.  If your substring was known to only ever be 2 words then I would just do an `Instr(mainstring, SubStringArray(0) & " " & SubStringArray(1)) > 0 Or Instr(mainstring, SubStringArray(1) & " " & SubStringArray(0)) > 0`, but once you have more than 2 substrings the number of potential matches increases very, very fast.

Comment: if you could split your main string into "words" then it might be do-able (eg replace all punctuation with spaces, then split on space and filter the array to remove empty elements).  Then find each search word's position and check the positions are in sequence with no gaps.